# Can I have a wildcard in map like this Map<Class<?>, ?>

Tags: java, generics

I have a private instance

```
private final Map<Class<?>, ?> map;
```

Syntactically, this is correct. What I want to do is this.

```
public class User {
}
public class UserSubclass extends User {
}
public class Role {
}

map.put(User.class, new User()); // valid
map.put(User.class, new UserSubclass()); // valid
map.put(Role.class, new Role()); // valid
// But when I do the following I need to get an error
map.put(User.class, new Role(); // invalid, compiler error
```

1. How should I declare the Map?
2. How can I instantiate an object of HashMap to this Map?

Comment: Related: [Generics and inheritance: need a complex Map instance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13845468/1225328)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this by default, but what you can do, is to create your own Generic Safe Map, which will work.

The GenericMap would look like this:

```
class GenericMap extends HashMap<Class<?>, Object> {

    public <T> T putClassAndInstance(Class<T> c, T o){
        return c.cast(super.put(c, o));
    }

    public <T> T getInstance(Class<T> c) {
        return c.cast(super.get(c));
    }
}
```

And can then be used like:

```
GenericMap map = new GenericMap();

map.putClassAndInstance(User.class, new User()); // valid
map.putClassAndInstance(User.class, new UserSubclass()); // valid
map.putClassAndInstance(Role.class, new Role()); // valid
map.putClassAndInstance(User.class, new Role()); // invalid, compiler error
```

This way, you don't have to create special methods for the User and Role, and still have the safety of not adding the wrong object for the wrong type.

Comment: I'd add an appropriate `getInstance` method as well (then it's basically what `ClassToInstanceMap` does).

Comment: Perfect. I like this answer. Very simple and neat!

Comment: Joachim, I've added your suggestion, and also removed the @SuppressWarnings by using the cast method.

Comment: +1 But I would recommend using composition instead of inheritance, so you can hide the underlying map's implementation.

Answer (score 5):

No, a simple `java.util.Map` does not support this. It is *statically* typed, and what you ask for is basically dynamic typing of one parameter based on the runtime-type of another one.

However, the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) class [`ClassToInstanceMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html) implements exactly what you want:

> A map, each entry of which maps a Java raw type to an instance of that type. In addition to implementing `Map`, the additional type-safe operations `putInstance(java.lang.Class<T>, T)` and `getInstance(java.lang.Class<T>)` are available.

Comment: Does it ? OP try to put a `User.class` with instance of Role class that are totally different by type hierarchy.

Comment: @Vash: read the comment in the code. He expected that line not to compile. And if he'd had used `ClassToInstanceMap` and `putInstance` then it *would* fail to compile.